# git checkout - lost all commits except for the initial commit

Tags: git

I have done a refactoring and commited it.
I have added a comment and remembered that I wanted to check that something did not change in the refactoring.
I executed

```
git stash
```

so that I could return to the last commit and executed

```
git checkout HEAD~
```

and got (as expected) to the last commit, which was one ahead of origin.

When I wanted to return to the most recent commit I executed

```
git checkout master
```

When I now open gitk, the history is empty, only the initial commit remains.
gitk claims both master and origin/master were at this only commit.

I have not executed any git commands other than `gitk` and `git status` in between.

I am lost. How do i get back to the most recent commit?

I am using git version 2.1.4.

Comment: First of all you can make a copy of your project folder (the one with .git folder *including* .git folder). There you can continue experiments without affecting the first folder.

Comment: Doing `git stash` followed by `git checkout HEAD~` and `git checkout master` brought me back to the most recent commit. Did you commit anything at all after `git checkout HEAD~`?

Comment: Can you run `history` in a terminal and make certain that you didn't run any additional commands? Also check `git reflog`.

Comment: @sp0gg yes, `history` shows, that I have not executed any other commands in between

Comment: @sp0gg thanks, I will take a look at `git reflog`. I don't know that command yet.

Comment: If you end up finding the hash of the missing commit, you can `git checkout <hash>` to verify the code, then `git reset --hard <hash>` to set the branch back to the commit.

Comment: @sp0gg thanks a lot, `git reflog` revealed the answer! So I... I don't know how to say that... it's too embarrassing... but it seems I was not working on the master branch...